# Shoring beams properly installed?

Tags: structural-engineering, foundations, home-improvement

Question about a home my wife and are looking at purchasing. The garage had an office/apartment on the second floor, and the seller disclosed that the floor had sagged and been fixed with shoring beams (I may have the wrong terminology).

We snapped some pictures and it looks like they are permanent rated beams, but I don’t know how to tell if they’re properly installed. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. [image: image of a few of the beams]

Comment: If you like the house otherwise, You have the option of hiring a home inspector who would validate (K)amran's answer. Since this was done by the previous owner, is should be remedied by them - assuming the office itself was permitted. If it wasn't, then you really have a can of worms on your hands. The supports may not be structurally necessary (but probably are). Maybe the current owner just didn't like the soft feel of the floor, or maybe he has a water bed up there.

Comment: Great point. There isn’t more up there than a bathroom, bed, desk, and tv. Funny enough it does feel rock solid when you’re walking around up there. 

It might be just a little too sketchy for us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not okay. Even as a short-term solution for a couple of days. If the building department knows about this it will red-tag the garage (prohibit entering it) until they pull a permit and do it right.

Even their insurance company would suspend the policy if they knew of illegal construction.

Beams have to be calculated. posts should be calculated and rest on a proper foundation with a proper baseplate. The fasteners should be code-approved. As it is if somebody inadvertently bumps gently into the columns with a car trying to park, the building will collapse on their head.

This is the textbook example of what a dangerous job, done by unprofessionals, is.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the input! I don’t know that this specific structure is insured etc. their disclosure mentions the floors sagged and this was the fix. I have no idea if the apartment is especially official at all. This area is all 100+ year old homes and stuff like this seems pretty common unfortunately.

Comment: The props solution is no good. Don't know if it was done by an engineer or a handyman. A deeper beam ( higher depth than width ) with supports inside opposite walls would be neater.